# Distance to the boundary and normal vector

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded with smooth boundary ($C^2$ at least). Let $x_0\in \partial\Omega$, we know that the outward normal vector is given by
$$ \mathbf{n}(x_0) = -\nabla d(x_0)$$
where $d(x) = \mathrm{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$ is the distance function. My question is, how to show that for $s$ small there holds
$$ d(x_0-s\mathbf{n}(x_0))  = s?$$

Edit: I meant the unit normal vector.

Comment: "**the** outward normal vector"?  There are infinitely many outward normal vectors.  Another one: twice the one you're thinking of.  Also, $\nabla d$ is undefined on $\partial\Omega$ (compare with $|x|$, which is nondifferentiable at $x = 0$), so $-\nabla d(x_0)$ does not exist.

Comment: In general, your claim about "... = s" is false.

Comment: @ Eric: the one-sided derivative should still exist, for example on $(-1,1)$, $d(x) = 1-|x|$ which is clearly well-defined at $-1$ and 1.

Comment: @ Wlog AA: what do you mean in general? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the usual approximation $f(x) \sim f(x_{0})+[(\nabla f)(x_{0})] \cdot (x-x_{0})$. Indeed, since $x_{0} \in \partial \Omega$, then $d(x_{0})=0$. Using this and the fact that $\mathbf{n}(x_{0})=-\nabla d(x_{0})$, we have
$$d(x_{0}-s\mathbf{n}(x_{0}))\sim d(x_{0})+\nabla d(x_{0}) \cdot ((x_{0}-s\mathbf{n}(x_{0}))-x_{0})=0-\mathbf{n}(x_{0}) \cdot (-s \mathbf{n}(x_{0}))=s.$$